# Multiple query results on one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to learn C#.net and figured with all the hype around .net core I'd start there, but I'm a little out of my depth.

I have a list of  (lets say 'Countries') from a database. I click on a country and it shows me details of the item. This works:

```
    // GET: Database/Details/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(Guid? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var country = await _context.countries.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id);
        if (subscription == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(country);
    }
```

On the details view, I want to show two tables.

The first being 'country', which will show generic information (Capital, Currency, Continent). I can currently do this fine.

The second being a list of cities (from a table called 'Cities'). How would I do this? I can't work out how to return a second result set to the view.

(Hope the analogy helped explain it!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return a ViewModel. So create a class `IndexViewModel` or how your action is called (this is just a best practice, you can name it how you want) and add 2 properties:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public List<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller return the model:

```
// GET: Database/Details/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(Guid? id)
{
    if (id == null || subscription == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var model = new IndexViewModel();
    model.Country = await _context.countries.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id);
    model.Cities = SomeFunction();

    return View(model);
}
```

In your View add a reference at the top of the document:

```
@model IndexViewModel
```

And, you can access the data by:

```
@Model.Country
@Model.Cities
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! The ViewModel was the bit I was missing, I think mostly because I wasn't sure what to google. Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create a ViewModel that gives you a place to store both lists and pass that to your view. Example below.

```
public class MyViewModel{
    public IEnumerable<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```